# Fokker-Planck: convection in two directions

Tags: probability, pde, differential-equations

I'm trying to simulate a Fokker-Planck process with the particles moving in direction A for fraction x of the time and direction B for (1-x). How do I set up the equation? Or is it possible for me to solve two Fokker-Planck equations, one for each advection component, and then sum the products of each with their corresponding fraction?

Comment: +1, because this is interesting, but you also haven't provided nearly enough information to get any (useful) help. Are 'A' and 'B' orthogonal (ie/ is this a 2d problem), or are you referring to two simultaneous applied advection effects in 1d. What boundary conditions are you interested in? Are you trying to solve for concentration (or heat)? For fluxes on boundaries? For survival functions? For mean first passage times?

Comment: Hm. 'A' and 'B' are just two arbitrary points of advection on a 2D landscape with zero-flux boundary conditions. What I'm working on is to numerically solve for the transient solution of a Fokker-Planck equation where the probability distribution represents the location of a migrating animal. Given an initial distribution, I like to see the movement dynamics when, at every time step, there's a chance x the animal moves towards attractor 'A' and a chance (1-x) it moves towards attractor 'B'. Please let me know if there's more I can clarify on (just started working with PDEs..).